# Where can I find a DNN6 module template for VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, dotnetnuke

I want to develop dnn 6 module in visual studio 2012 but all the vs 2012 plug in are require minimum dnn 7 versions.
where can i find visual studio 2012 plug in that i can develop for dnn 6?

Answer (score 1):

Use this Chris Hammond's DotNetNuke module template, you can still get previous releases of his template from CodePlex. This one is the last release for DNN 6

[DotNetNuke Project Templates V1.1 for VS2012](http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/releases/view/93333)

Check out the blog post for all of the details about this release.

[Release Info](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/EntryId/3471/New-Visual-Studio-2012-Project-Templates-for-DotNetNuke.aspx)

Happy coding!

Comment: I'm a big believer of moving to DNN7, but if you're gotta stick with 6, that is the proper link